# I have A problem with dividing the value of 0 by 0 in an Access database

Tags: vb.net

When I try to extract the result of Division 2 Field from table in access database
If I have a value of 0 an error occurs

```
sqlSTR = "SELECT TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_Org_Price2/TBL_Stocks_Balances.Item_QTY AS ['Price']FROM (((TBL_Category_Item_File INNER JOIN TBL_Suppliers_Product ON TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_ID = TBL_Suppliers_Product.Item_ID) INNER JOIN TBL_Suppliers ON TBL_Suppliers_Product.Supp_ID = TBL_Suppliers.Supp_ID) INNER JOIN TBL_Sub_categories ON TBL_Category_Item_File.ID_Sub_categories = TBL_Sub_categories.ID_Sub_categories) INNER JOIN TBL_Stocks_Balances ON (TBL_Stocks_Balances.Item_ID = TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_ID) AND (TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_BarCode = TBL_Stocks_Balances.Item_Barcode)  WHERE  tbl_Category_Item_File.Catg_ID =" & Split(cmblist.Text, " - ")(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to avoid the error, you can use a CASE statement in your query to check for a 0 value in the Item_Org_Price2 field and return a different value if it is 0. For example, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_Org_Price2 = 0 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_Org_Price2/TBL_Stocks_Balances.Item_QTY 
END AS ['Price']
FROM (((TBL_Category_Item_File INNER JOIN TBL_Suppliers_Product ON TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_ID = TBL_Suppliers_Product.Item_ID) INNER JOIN TBL_Suppliers ON TBL_Suppliers_Product.Supp_ID = TBL_Suppliers.Supp_ID) INNER JOIN TBL_Sub_categories ON TBL_Category_Item_File.ID_Sub_categories = TBL_Sub_categories.ID_Sub_categories) INNER JOIN TBL_Stocks_Balances ON (TBL_Stocks_Balances.Item_ID = TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_ID) AND (TBL_Category_Item_File.Item_BarCode = TBL_Stocks_Balances.Item_Barcode)  WHERE  tbl_Category_Item_File.Catg_ID =" & Split(cmblist.Text, " - ")(0)
```